# Inserting a new Sheet from a Template into an existing spreadsheet in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I know how to insert a new *blank* sheet in Google Sheets to an existing spreadsheet, but how do you insert a new Sheet from a Template to an existing spreadsheet document?

For example, if I have a spreadsheet that was created from the "To Do" template, I'd like to add a new sheet to that document using the "To Do" template again, not just a blank sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy a sheet from the Template to another spreadsheet file, open the Template spreadsheet, click the dart ▼ in the tab bar at the bottom of the browser window, and choose **Copy to > Existing spreadsheet**.

To copy multiple sheets from one spreadsheet file to another while keeping formulas that use cross-sheet range references working, follow the instructions in [Is there a way I can merge spreadsheets together without losing references?](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/25896767?msgid=25901483)

Comment: I will test this soon, and vote to accept if it works! :)

Comment: Validated. Fantastic. Thanks @doubleunary.